# Python Async Requests with RabbitMQ Consumer

Tags: python, request, rabbitmq, python-asyncio

Suppose i have the following system that is designed to make async requests to some url using asyncio

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

data = [...]

try:
    tasks = [self.make_request(key, item) for key, item in data]
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
finally:
    loop.close()

def make_request(key, item):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=self.headers) as session:
        response = await session.post("http:/xx.com", json={"item": item})
        print("OK.")
```

data variable holds all the messages i want to process and using them with asyncio works fine. 
Then RabbitMQ gets in the way and consuming from a queue blocks anything after basic_consume line.

```
def handle(message):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    data = [...]

    try:
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.make_request(0, message))
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.close()

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(#...params)
channel = connection.channel()

channel.basic_consume(
    queue='somequeue',
    on_message_callback=handle,
)

channel.start_consuming()
```

handle method gets called every time consumer consumes a new message,
passing message parameter as each item in data variable.
So instead of having all coroutines at once i end up having them one by one,
how should the code be at this point ?

Comment: Don't use a `BlockingConnection`, use an [`AsyncioConnection`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/asyncio_consumer.html) instead.

Comment: Connection type does not solve it, there is no way of controlling loop.run_until_complete(tasks), because every time a msg comes in it will run the handle method, i just dont know where to put loop.run_until_complete(tasks) part ?